# PDF header signature not found error?

Tags: pdf, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on Asp.Net MVC application with Azure. When I upload the PDF document to Azure blob storage it will uploaded perfectly by using  below code.

```
           var filename = Document.FileName;
           var contenttype = Document.ContentType;

           int pdfocument = Request.ContentLength;

        //uploading document in to azure blob

         CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

           var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount(FromConfigurationSetting("Connection"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
           CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");
           container.CreateIfNotExists();
            var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
            container.SetPermissions(permissions);
            string uniqueBlobName = string.Format(filename );
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
            blob.Properties.ContentType = ;
            blob.UploadFromStream(Request.InputStream);
```

after uploading the document to blob trying to to read the pdf document getting an error "PDF header signature not found."     that erorr code    is

```
          byte[] pdf = new byte[pdfocument];
          HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Read(pdf, 0, pdfocument);               
          PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);     //error getting here
```

and one more thing I forgot i.e if we comment the above code(uploading document in to Azure blob) then am not getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

In your combined use case you try to read Request.InputStream twice, once during upload and once later when trying to read it into your `byte[] pdf` --- when you read it first, you read it until its end, so the second read most likely did not get any data at all.

As you anyways intend to read the PDF into memory (the afore mentioned `byte[] pdf`), you could in your combined use case

- first read the data into that array

  ```
  int pdfocument = Request.ContentLength;
  byte[] pdf = new byte[pdfocument];
  HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Read(pdf, 0, pdfocument);
  ```
- then upload that array using [CloudBlob.UploadByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee772816.aspx)

  ```
  var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount(FromConfigurationSetting("Connection"));
  [...]
  CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
  blob.Properties.ContentType = ; // <--- something missing in your code...
  blob.UploadByteArray(pdf);      // <--- upload byte[] instead of stream
  ```
- and then feed your PDF reader

  ```
  PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
  ```

This way you read the stream only once, and a byte[] should be re-usable...

Comment: Hi Andrew,Now am upload the byte array in to blob instead of stream now am out of the pdf header issue.thanks a lot for your valuable info.I want to ask one thing on this.when i opened the pdf document in the browser using blob url it is opening along with one pop up .the pop up is “This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader.  The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available.  Please contact the author for the original version of this document.” This error getting in Adobe Reader 9.0 version,but not getting in 11.0 version

Comment: Does that also happen with the same PDF before uploading? Or did something break in the upload process? If you are not sure, please provide both the PDF before upload and after.

Comment: It's happens after not before.when i upload that PDF before it' open's normally.not getting pop up message.

Comment: @PCSSCP Please supply bothe the PDFs before and after for inspection.